# Unable to remove rows from table

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the table with following data in it

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> cat </td>
        <td> dog </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> hen </td>
        <td> cock </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to delete the row based on the particular data given in table.
But I don't have any idea on how to delete the rows based on the particular data

Comment: Not sure how your tables are created but if you can add a class to each row `<tr class="cat" >`, then you can select and delete them like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table');
var filterInput = document.querySelector('#filter');

filterInput.onkeyup = function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var td = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var rows = [];
    [].slice.call(td).forEach(function (el, i) {
        if (el.textContent === val) {
            rows.push(el);
        }
    });
    rows.forEach(function(el) {
        el.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    });
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Hide row containing...">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cat</td>
        <td>dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hen</td>
        <td>cock</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the required element and then use `style property to hide it`. *In the example, I went onto hide the table data element corresponding to the data `dog`.*

```js
var tds = $("td");
for(var i =0 ; i< tds.length ; i++)
{
  var tdval = tds[i].innerHTML;
  if(tdval.trim()=="dog")
  {
    document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> cat </td>
    <td> dog </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> hen </td>
    <td> cock </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```